# Combination of NAT, DHCP, and OpenVPN on lubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, iptables, openvpn

Okay, so I've got a set up, where eth0 my internal IP address (192.168.1.3) it has been configured as my default gateway using the iptables this

> sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
>
> sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
>
> sudo iptables –-table nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE

Where eth2 is my static ip for internet

That works fine, I can access internet from any computer on my network via DHCP (192.168.1.10-200)

Everything stops working when I run openvpn

Here's my config file
http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7556511/

That config works without the NAT, as in on the computer I can browse the web, and if I do

> curl ifconfig.me

it gives me a remote ip address from my VPN provider.

When I say fails on other computers, I mean I can't load pages, I can't ping, nothing works outside of the network (But I can still SSH in on the internal interface

Comment: troubleshoothing this with someone on IRC the output of > cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward  is 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your iptables, the command:

```
  iptables –-table nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE
```

should be modified to

```
 iptables –-table nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

If your interface is not called tun0, please change accordingly (BTW, the very same applies if you have a *tap* interface, just use tap0 in tun0 stead).

In OpenVPN, all traffic exits your pc through the bridge, not the ethernet interface. You cannot however apply iptables to a bridge (that requires *ebtables*), but you can circumvent the problem by applying iptables to the virtual interface.

Comment: Does this change have the added benifit that the internet will go down if the vpn link fails?

Comment: @HilarieAK If you call it an added benefit, then yes, it does. When you are off the OpenVPN, you must re-issue the original *iptables* command. You may want to find a way to script it.

Comment: For the person who finds this post 5 years from now, could you update your answer to go -o tun[X] some how I managed to type it in write before doing the /etc/rc.local thing, actually on it, and spent the last half an hour messing with that.

Comment: @HilarieAK I just modified my answer as per your suggestion.

Comment: @MariusMatutae the people of the future thank you! I'd up-vote you but I don't have 15 rep yet.

Comment: @HilarieAK Now you do, lol.